# Simplify Equation with variable unequal to zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I simplify the following equation with Mathematica assuming z!=0?

I have the following code:

```
eq := (x + (x^2 + y^2) (Sqrt[c^2]))* z == 0
Simplify[eq, {z != 0}]
```

Expected output:
`(x + (x^2 + y^2) (Sqrt[c^2]))==0`

Instead Mathematica gives
`(x + Sqrt[c^2] (x^2 + y^2)) z == 0`

So in short Mathematica should remove the z.

Comment: `Thread[eq/z, Equal]`

Comment: Yes but how can mathematica do this automatically?
It is strange that if you remove any part from eq, e.g. the Sqrt[c^2], then Simplify works.

Comment: It will not. The function `Simplify` does not work like this. Simplify tries expanding, factoring, and doing many other transformations on expressions, keeping track of the simplest form obtained. It does not change the content of the expression. That is, it does not through parts of the expression away under some pretext. Please have a look into Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/Simplify/Details and Options.